# Short sentence with adjective and adverb

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, sentence

I think that this is a problem of the usage of adjectives and adverbs (that's why I chose this title):

I have a sentence in my presentation, which clarifies that a procedure uses only observations which are known, so I write:

> Uses only known observations.

or do I have to write:

> Only known observations are used.

or is the long version necessary:

> Uses only observations(,) which are known.

(I'm not sure about the comma)

Comment: Your first and third options are actually not sentences at all. Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: Ok, assume there is an "It" before. So It uses....

Comment: A presentation may have large quantities of non-sentences, e.g. bullet points. The first option is an acceptable bullet point. To be a sentence, it needs a subject ("it"). The second option is acceptable everywhere, and the third one has no place in a presentation (too long-winded).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are including this brief phrase (not a full sentence), then either of your first two options would be acceptable.

But on a separate point, if your presentation is describing a procedure that *has already been carried out*, i.e. if you are describing what was down *in the past*, then you may wish to use the *past tense*, instead of the present tense. In that case it would be:

> *Used* only known observations.
>   Only known observations *were* used.

Answer (score -1):

Only known observations are used.